# vehicleList array not sorting and receiving a run time error

Tags: java, comparable

I am getting an error when running my main method and I cannot figure out what I have wrong. The error I'm seeing is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Car cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable.

The error is occurring when calling on the `listByOwner` method,  `Arrays.sort(vehicleList)`.  I do not believe I have two vehicleList arrays, as I know that could possibly cause an issue sorting my vehicleList array.

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class UseTaxList {
   private String taxDistrict;
   private Vehicle[] vehicleList;
   private String[] excludedRecords;

  public UseTaxList() {
      taxDistrict = "not yet assigned";
      vehicleList = new Vehicle[0];
      excludedRecords = new String[0];
   }

   public void readVehicleFile(String fileNameIn)  
      throws FileNotFoundException { 
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileNameIn));
      taxDistrict = scanner.nextLine().trim();
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {
     String s = scanner.nextLine().trim();
     Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(s);
     lineScanner.useDelimiter(";");
     char vehicleType = lineScanner.next().toUpperCase().trim().charAt(0);
     String owner = lineScanner.next().trim();
     String yearMakeModel = lineScanner.next().trim();
     String v = lineScanner.next().trim();
     String aF = lineScanner.next().trim();


     switch (vehicleType) {
        case 'C':
           double carValue = Double.parseDouble(v);
           boolean carAltFuel = Boolean.parseBoolean(aF);
           Car newCar = new Car(owner, yearMakeModel, carValue, carAltFuel);
           addVehicle(newCar);
           break;

        case 'T':
           double truckValue = Double.parseDouble(v);
           boolean truckAltFuel = Boolean.parseBoolean(aF);
           String t = lineScanner.next().trim();
           double tons = Double.parseDouble(t);
           Truck newTruck = new Truck(owner, yearMakeModel, truckValue,
              truckAltFuel, tons);
           addVehicle(newTruck);
           break;

        case 'S':
           double semiValue = Double.parseDouble(v);
           boolean semiAltFuel = Boolean.parseBoolean(aF);
           String st = lineScanner.next().trim();
           double semiTons = Double.parseDouble(st);
           String ax = lineScanner.next().trim();
           int axle = Integer.parseInt(ax);
           SemiTractorTrailer newSemi = new SemiTractorTrailer(owner, 
              yearMakeModel, semiValue, semiAltFuel, semiTons, axle);
           addVehicle(newSemi);
           break;

        case 'M':
           String e = lineScanner.next().trim();
           double engSize = Double.parseDouble(e);
           double mValue = Double.parseDouble(v);
           boolean mAltFuel = Boolean.parseBoolean(aF);
           Motorcycle newMotorcycle = new Motorcycle(owner, 
              yearMakeModel, mValue, mAltFuel, engSize);
           addVehicle(newMotorcycle);
           break;

        default:
           addExcludedRecords("Excluded Records:\n" + s);
           break;         }    

      }   
   }

   public String getTaxDistrict() {
      return taxDistrict;
   }

   public void setTaxDistrict(String taxDistrictIn) {
      taxDistrict = taxDistrictIn;
   }

   public Vehicle[] getVehicleList() {
      return vehicleList;
   }

   public String[] getExcludedRecords() {
      return excludedRecords;
   }

   public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicleIn) {
      vehicleList = Arrays.copyOf(vehicleList, vehicleList.length + 1);
      vehicleList[vehicleList.length - 1] = vehicleIn;
    }

   public void addExcludedRecords(String recordsIn) {
      excludedRecords = Arrays.copyOf(excludedRecords, 
       excludedRecords.length + 1);
       excludedRecords[excludedRecords.length - 1] = recordsIn;
   }

   public String toString() {
      String output = "";
     for (Vehicle v1 : vehicleList) {
         output += "\n" + v1 + "\n";      }
      return output;
   } 

   public double calculateTotalUseTax() {
      double total = 0.0;
      for (Vehicle v1 : vehicleList) {
         total += v1.useTax();
      }
      return total;
   }

   public double calculateTotalValue() {
      double total = 0.0;
       for (Vehicle v1 : vehicleList) {
         total += v1.getValue();
     }
      return total;
   }

public String summary() {
   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##,###.00");
    String output = "";
   output += "------------------------------\n";
   output += "Summary for " + taxDistrict + "\n";
   output += "------------------------------";
   output += "\nNumber of Vehicles: " + vehicleList.length;
   output += "\nTotal Value: $" + formatter.format(calculateTotalValue());
   output += "\nTotal Use Tax: $" + formatter.format(calculateTotalUseTax())
       + "\n";
   return output;
 }

 public String listByOwner() {  
     Arrays.sort(vehicleList);
     String output = "------------------------------\n";
     output += "Vehicles by Owner\n";
     output += "------------------------------\n";
     for (Vehicle v1 : vehicleList) {
        output += "\n" + v1 + "\n";
     }
     return output;
 }

public String listByUseTax() {
  Arrays.sort(vehicleList, new UseTaxComparator());
  String output = "------------------------------\n";
  output += "Vehicles by Use Tax\n";
  output += "------------------------------\n";
  for (Vehicle v1 : vehicleList) {
     output += "\n" + v1 + "\n";
  }

  return output;  
 }

public String excludedRecordsList() {
  String output = "";
  output += "------------------------------\n";
  output += "Excluded Records\n";
  output += "------------------------------\n";
     for (String v1 : excludedRecords) {
     output += "\n" + v1 + "\n";
     }
 return output;  
   } 

 }
```

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code. Does your `Car` class implement `Comparable`? (or extend a class that does?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you're getting, your `Vehicle` class doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface, so you'll have to explicitly pass a `Comparator` to the `sort` call:

```
Arrays.sort(vehicleList, Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getOwner));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you must implement `Comparable` interface in your `Car` class to make `Arrays.sort` work... If you don't, sort doesn't know when a `Car` is "higher" than other car.

Comment: My car class extends a vehicle class, and that vehicle class needed to have the Comparable interface added.  Thanks!